# Div box inside A link, looking to minimize A link cursor box area

Tags: html, css

I'm a terrible explaining which is why I provided an Image of my issue.

[Issue at hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzcFl.jpg)

```css
.body {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.column1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.boxhunter {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 180px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center center, #ABD473 0%, #16150c 120%);
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 3%;
  margin: 10px;
}

a {
  color: black;
  font-family: Dwarvesc;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="column1">
      <a href="./classes/druid/druidindex.html">
        <div class="boxdruid"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/driud.png">Druid</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#hunter">
        <div class="boxhunter"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/hunter.png">Hunter</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#mage">
        <div class="boxmage"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/mage.png">Mage</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#paladin">
        <div class="boxpaladin"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/paladin.png">Paladin</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="column1">
      <a href="#priest">
        <div class="boxpriest"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/priest.png">Priest</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#rogue">
        <div class="boxrogue"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/rogue.png">Rogue</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#warlock">
        <div class="boxwarlock"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/warlock.png">Warlock</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#warrior">
        <div class="boxwarrior"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/warrior.png">Warrior</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The dotted red lines represent the box that's wrapped by the A link because I want the whole box to be clickable.  Is there a way to make it so that the A link just targets the div box so the cursor can be default in between each box? Thanks

Comment: You should post the relevant CSS as well.

Comment: Can you post your CSS too? Your issue isn't with the HTML, it's with the styling.

Comment: hey guys, I just added the CSS to it as well, it's a bit messy but hope it helps you guys!

Comment: *"... so the cursor can be default in between each box?"* I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to change your HTML layout.

In fact, you only need to change 2 lines of your CSS!
Your problem was a simple padding/margin issue.

Here is a working snippet, I commented where I modified:

```css
.body {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.column1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

[class*="box"] { /* Changed class for test purpose */
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 180px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center center, #ABD473 0%, #16150c 120%);
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 3%;
  /* margin: 10px; Removed */
}

a {
  color: black;
  font-family: Dwarvesc;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin: 15px; /* Modified */
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="column1">
      <a href="./classes/druid/druidindex.html">
        <div class="boxdruid"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/driud.png">Druid</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#hunter">
        <div class="boxhunter"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/hunter.png">Hunter</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#mage">
        <div class="boxmage"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/mage.png">Mage</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#paladin">
        <div class="boxpaladin"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/paladin.png">Paladin</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="column1">
      <a href="#priest">
        <div class="boxpriest"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/priest.png">Priest</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#rogue">
        <div class="boxrogue"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/rogue.png">Rogue</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#warlock">
        <div class="boxwarlock"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/warlock.png">Warlock</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#warrior">
        <div class="boxwarrior"><img class="profsimage" src="./randomimages/warrior.png">Warrior</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're the best! That worked flawlessly :) I don't have enough points to upvote, so here's a huge cheers xD